# Android - Save the realmlist inside a realm object

Tags: android, realm-list, realm-java

I have a model

```
public class Response extends RealmObject {

        @PrimaryKey
        private String _id;
        private RealmList<TaskResponse> task_responses;
        private AssignmentRecord assignmentRecord;
        private ResponseStatistic responseStats;
}
```

Now, i am trying to save task_responses realmlist inside the Response but couldn't succeed, below is the relevant code:

```
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    response.setTaskResponses(taskResponses);
    response.setAssignmentRecord(assignmentRecord);
    response.setResponseStats(responseStatistic);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

When I placed debugger before this line

```
response.setTaskResponses(taskResponses);
```

the size of taskResponses was 5 but after execution it becomes empty and realm stores a empty list.

TaskResponse Model :

```
    public class TaskResponse extends RealmObject {

        @PrimaryKey
        private String _id;
        private String taskId;
        private Boolean answered;
        private String answer;
        private TaskStatistic taskStat;
    }
```

Comment: All TaskResponse objects should be a realm handled objects

Answer (score 2):

You can save like this it will work

```
Realm mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    RealmList<TaskResponse> taskResponseslist = new RealmList();
    taskResponseslist.addAll(taskResponses);
    response.setTaskResponses(taskResponseslist);
    response.setAssignmentRecord(assignmentRecord);
    response.setResponseStats(responseStatistic);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
    mRealm.close();
```

Comment: taskResponses are not getting saved, rest are sorted

Comment: I have declared mRealm already but not able to store the realmList taskResponses into response

Comment: you need to add data into list and then after commit into response model

Comment: befor mRealm.beginTransaction();  
the taskResponses.size() returned 5 but after mRealm.commitTransaction(); taskResponses.size() returns 0

Comment: already answered your question look at my answer it will work